# deeplearningのフレームワークCaffeのビルドに関して

Tags: c++, macos, boost

CNNを使いたく思い、Caffeのインストールを試みました。
[こちらのサイト](http://qiita.com/t-hiroyoshi/items/3bba01dd11b1241f1336)を参考にし、記載されていることはひと通り行ったつもりですが、make all でエラーが発生してしまいます。
おそらくboostまわりのエラーだとは思うのですが、調べてもわからなかったため質問しました。
OS：mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
CPU: 3.1 GHz Intel Core i7
boost：1.55
python-boost：1.55
（依存ライブラリに関しては全てbrewでインストールしました）
以下にエラーメッセージを記載します。
何か対処法をご存知のかたいましたらよろしくお願いします。

```
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
CXX src/caffe/common.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/once.hpp:20:
In file included from/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/once_atomic.hpp:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/atomic.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/atomic/atomic.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/platform.hpp:22:
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:961:64: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'storage_type' (aka 'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
explicit base_atomic(value_type const& v) BOOST_NOEXCEPT : v_(0)
                                                           ^  ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type' for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:968:22: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'storage_type' (aka 'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
    storage_type tmp = 0;
                 ^     ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type &' for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:983:22: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'storage_type' (aka 'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
    storage_type tmp = 0;
                 ^     ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type &' for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:997:22: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'storage_type' (aka 'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
    storage_type expected_s = 0, desired_s = 0;
                 ^            ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type &' for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:997:38: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'storage_type' (aka 'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
    storage_type expected_s = 0, desired_s = 0;
                                 ^           ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type &' for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:1013:22: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'storage_type' (aka 'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
    storage_type expected_s = 0, desired_s = 0;
                 ^            ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type &' for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:1013:38: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'storage_type' (aka 'boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type')
    storage_type expected_s = 0, desired_s = 0;
                                 ^           ~
/usr/local/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:932:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const boost::atomics::detail::storage128_type &' for 1st argument
struct BOOST_ALIGNMENT(16) storage128_type
                       ^
7 errors generated.
```

Comment: [Compilation error with Boost/Thread.hpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476267/compilation-error-with-boost-thread-hpp)